# What does @ do, work and mean in PHP?

Tags: php

Hey Stackoverflow community.
I had some issues with my code yesterday and somehow solved it by adding @ in front of some of my statements such as this

```
 if (@!empty($_SESSION["customer]) {
   //code
}
```

I had never seen it before but it worked perfectly. I have searched for it on Google but i can't find any useful description about the @ in PHP. I want to hear if anyone knows what it does, how it works and mean in PHP. Thanks!

Comment: it hides notices.It suppresses error messages

Comment: nullify error reporting

Comment: errors are there for a reason and you shouldn't ignore them. Best you should do here is define your variable properly to avoid such errors

Comment: In this particular code, `@` shouldn't fix anything.

Comment: Stay away from it. You won't regret.

Answer (score 1):

The @ surpresses warning and error messages.

For example, if you run the command `is_file("text.txt")` and text.txt does not exist, you get a warning message. If you run `@is_file("text.txt")` you won't get this warning message.

Comment: Note that you should avoid using the @ operator, since it will make debugging your code much harder. In the example posted above, the offending code should be wrapped with a "file_exists()" statement.